# How do I receive a data buffer (octet stream) on the client side in JavaScript as a file?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, buffer, binary-data

I have an endpoint in node/express which does something to this effect

```
https.get(EXTERNAL_ENDPOINT, response =>
                {                    
                    const data : ArrayBuffer[] = [];
                    response.on("data", chunk =>
                    {
                        data.push(chunk);
                    });

                    response.on("end", () =>
                    {
                        res.setHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
                        return res.status(200).send(Buffer.from(data.toString(), "base64"));
                    });
                });
```

I am doing this to redirect a binary data stream I receive from an external endpoint to my client.

How do I receive this binary data on the client side as a downloadable file? It can be a pdf that can be downloaded or something like an image which has to be displayed in the browser on the website (as part of the website).